# Negative expected value for iid standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, integration

I would like to show analytically that:

$$\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{(X_2-X_1)(Y_2-Y_1)}{|X_2+Y_2-X_1-Y_1|}\right] < 0$$

I would be happy just showing that this is true when $(X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2)$ are iid standard normal random variables, but a more general demonstration would be even better.

Montecarlo integration shows the expectation to be strongly negative (much less than zero) for pretty much any distribution governing the $X_1, Y_1, X_2, Y_2$.

Comment: Letting $A= (X_2-X_1)/\sqrt 2$ and $B=(Y_2-Y_1)/\sqrt 2,$ you have $A,B \sim \text{i.i.d.} \operatorname N(0,1),$ and $$ \frac{(X_2-X_1)(Y_2-Y_1)}{|X_2+Y_2-X_1-Y_1|} = \frac{AB}{|A+B|}. $$ So your question is somewhat more complicated than it needs to be. $\qquad$

Comment: Many thanks Michael, true it can be simplified in this way; in fact this is the way I've been attacking the problem. My hope is to be able to show that the inequality can be satisfied in a way not restricted to standard normal, but I'd be very happy if it could at least be shown for the standard normal case. Of course, it can still be formulated in the way you state for the more general problem, where A and B are defined generically as spacings distributions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It doesn't really make a difference with the expectation being less than or greater than $0$, but with your substitution, it is $\frac{(X_2-X_1)(Y_2-Y_1)}{|X_2+Y_2-X_1-Y_1|} = \frac{A\sqrt{2} B \sqrt{2}}{|A \sqrt{2} + B \sqrt{2}|} = \frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{2}} AB}{|A+B|}$, not $\frac{AB}{|A+B|}$

Comment: When you write that the inequality seems to be true for "pretty much any distribution", is that where $X_1, Y_1, X_2, Y_2$ are iid, or does that apply to any combination of different distributions?

Comment: hi Varun, thanks for your interest. so the full problem is one in which you have two couples (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2) drawn from some bivariate distribution. i have performed montecarlo integration to compute the expectation with several different distributions with zero covariance or with randomly-assigned covariance. doesn't seem to matter. the expectation is always negative.

Comment: I don't think the expectation exists. Are you sure of this result?

Comment: Actually, Varun's solution is perfect for my purposes, because I am looking for a qualitative answer where the difference between -6 and $$-\infty$$ is immaterial.

Comment: I am pretty sure the corresponding integral diverges (it is not $-\infty$), therefore no question of the expectation being $<0$.

Comment: Not sure how divergence is different from the solution going to infinity in either the positive or negative direction. My understanding is that the expectation in question will depend on $ f(x,y) $. For some $ f(x,y) $, the integral will be a finite negative number; for others, it will be negative infinity. I think, however, that the fact of it being negative is inescapable, because $ f(x,y) \ge 0 $

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint of Michael Hardy and letting $X = \frac{X_2 - X_1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $Y = \frac{Y_2 - Y_1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $$\frac{(X_2-X_1)(Y_2-Y_1)}{|X_2+Y_2-X_1-Y_1|} = \frac{\sqrt{2} XY}{|X+Y|}$$

So it suffices to show that $$\mathbb{E} (Z) < 0$$ where $Z =  \frac{XY}{|X+Y|}$ and $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$.

An intuitive explanation first: For $Z > 0$ to be true, $X$ and $Y$ have to be of the same sign. Because they are of the same sign, this makes $|X+Y|$ larger (on average) and the overall "weight" of $Z$ smaller. On the other hand for $Z < 0$ to be true, $X$ and $Y$ have to have different signs. Because of this, $|X+Y|$ is smaller (on average), and the weight of $Z$ is larger. This makes the overall expected value negative.

A more mathematical explanation: The expected value of $Z$ is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(y) \frac{xy}{|x+y|} \, dx \, dy$$

Because $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric about $0$, this can be rewritten as $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(y) \left(\frac{xy}{x+y} + \frac{(-x)(-y)}{|-x-y|} + \frac{(-x)y}{|(-x)+y|} + \frac{x(-y)}{|x+(-y)|}  \right) dx \, dy$$

The integrand can be simplified to $$2xy f_X(x) f_Y(y)\left(\frac{1}{x+y} - \frac{1}{|x-y|} \right)$$

It is easy to see that $\frac{1}{x+y} - \frac{1}{|x-y|} < 0$ for $x, y > 0$ since $$|x-y| < x+y $$ $$\frac{1}{x+y}<\frac{1}{\left|x-y\right|}$$ $$\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{1}{\left|x-y\right|}<0$$

and so the integrand will be negative. Therefore the expected value of $Z$ will be negative. A similar explanation would work for any $X, Y$ that are both symmetric about $x = 0$ and thus also any $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ such that $X_1$, $X_2$ are iid and $Y_1, Y_2$ are iid ($X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ don't have to be iid).

Comment: Wow, many thanks Varun!! Your intuitive explanation is right on, and the logic in your mathematical development looks good, as is the logic of your extension to cases in which X1,X2 are iid and Y1,Y2 are iid -- this is also key for my purposes. Do you see any hope of further generalization? For example if X and Y are not symmetric about zero?  Also please send me your contact info. I am at  pgerrish (at) unm (dot) com.

Comment: The inequality will not even be true if $X, Y$ are both strictly negative or strictly positive. I'm not sure if it is possible to show the expected value is less than $0$ for more general $X, Y$ without knowing the exact distribution of $X, Y$.

Comment: please send me your email address here or to my email address (pgerrish (at) unm (dot) edu), and I will send you the paper for which your derivation is relevant. The paper is in the area of evolution. At the very least, you should be in the acknowledgements!

Comment: My previous comment was directed to Varun Vejalla. I am new to stackexchange and the "@" tagging did not work for me, for some reason.

Comment: @dvorak when you say "if $X$ and $Y$ are not symmetric around zero": if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid then the distribution of $X_2 - X_1$ is symmetric around zero, is that helpful?